# Pygame image moving without proper input

Tags: python, image, animation, pygame, mouse

I recently started tinkering a bit with pygame and I made  this little piece of code (following a tutorial):

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
display_width = 1920
display_height = 1080
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

pygame.display.set_caption("Galvadon's Adventure")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

galvadon = pygame.image.load("galvadonModelVersion1.0.png")

def galvadonIsHere(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(galvadon,(x,y))

x = (display_width * 0.30)
y = (display_height * 0.2)
y_change = 0

crashed = False

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white) 
        galvadonIsHere(x,y)
        print(event)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

and to an extent this code works, the problem is that after I move the image using the up and down arrows, the image starts to respond to any mouse movement by just gliding in the direction it last moved towards. I probably missed something out, but I just can't seem to find what it is. I looked at various websites looking for the answer but I couldn't find anyone asking a similar question, hence why I make this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the while loop. The if statement for keyup is in the if statement for keydown, so it is preventing it from working. The following solves your problem:

```
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
        else:
            y_change = 0
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of things that you can do better here. But lets start with fixing the issue.

'Bug' is that after you press keys, `y_change` is set and never reset for next engine loop. This should help you:

```
...
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 5
            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_change = -5
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                    y_change = 0
        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        galvadonIsHere(x, y)
        print(event)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

        y_change = 0
...
```

Pay close attention at the last line in my snippet. Here you reset `y_change` so in next engine loop, whatever happens or doesn't, it wont affect position of your image.

#### Refactor and improve

First, you can agree that checking if `event` type is `KEY_DOWN` and nesting checks if it is particular key button is pain to read and work with. Not to mention you check if `event` type is `KEYUP` even though you know that is `KEYDOWN` here:

```
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
    ...
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_change = 0
```

So, what I do is define helper function, that can be usual one or `lambda`. Now, many would argue that `lambda` functions are affecting readability but here it can certainly help you with these checks.

Example:

```
key_pressed = lambda event, key: event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == key

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
            break
        elif key_pressed(event, pygame.K_DOWN):
            y_change = 5
        elif key_pressed(event, pygame.K_UP):
            y_change = -5
        else:
            y_change = 0

        y += y_change

        gameDisplay.fill(white)
        galvadonIsHere(x, y)
        print(event)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(30)

        y_change = 0
```

One more thing, pay attention at condition that there was `pygame.QUIT` event. `break` exits the `for` loop and then `while` loop ends too. This way you do not process any queued events, nor you update and blit image.